# ¿Cómo detectar cuando un NestedScrollView o un RecyclerView llegan abajo (bottom)?

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview, nestedscrollview

**Edit:**

*setOnScrollChangeListener* es el método que utilizo para detectar cuando se está scrolleando en un NestedScrollView... El problema es que en una de mis apps este método funciona y en otra app directamente no responde. Será un error de gradle? Por qué en una app funciona y en otra no?

**Descripción:**

Programé una pequeña app siguiendo un mini tutorial para realizar una paginación de 10 en 10 para un recyclerview. Cada vez que se llega al piso (bottom) se llama a un método que va a cargar los próximos 10 items.

Como este código funciona, decidí replicarlo en otro de mis proyectos pero el problema es que en este segundo proyecto, por algún motivo, no está funcionando.

**Adjunto mi código XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
   android:id="@+id/nested"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:contentDescription="@string/app_name">

   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:contentDescription="@string/app_name">

       <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
           xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
           android:id="@+id/adView"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/twentydp"
           ads:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
           ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
           ads:adSize="BANNER"
           ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
       </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/txt_resultados_lore"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/tendp"
           android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/twentydp"
           android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
           android:fontFamily="@font/nunito"
           android:text="@string/resultados_lore"
           android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
           android:textSize="@dimen/thirteensp"
           app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/adView"/>

       <View
           android:id="@+id/view_barra1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="@dimen/twodp"
           android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/tendp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/tendp"
           android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/tendp"
           android:background="@color/light_gray2"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_resultados_lore"
           app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
           android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

       <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
           android:id="@+id/recycler_animales_filtrados"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fivedp"
           tools:listitem="@layout/item_row_recycler_filtered_animals"
           android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view_barra1" />

       <ProgressBar
           android:id="@+id/progressBar"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Adjunto código java del listener:**

```
binding.nested.setOnScrollChangeListener((NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener) (v, scrollX, scrollY, oldScrollX, oldScrollY) -> {
        p.showToast(getActivity(),"test-text");
        if(scrollY == v.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight()){
            page++;
            binding.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

Como mencioné arriba, este listener funciona sin problemas para NestedScrollView en el proyecto que importé, pero en mi nuevo proyecto, ni siquiera funciona el listener (al deslizarse ni siquiera se muestra el toast).

Dado que no encontré la forma de hacerlo funcionar, decidí ponerle un listener al recycler el cual si está detectando el scroll (muestra toast al scrollear), pero no detecta cuando se llega a la parte inferior (bottom).

**Otra solución que probé:**

```
binding.recyclerAnimalesFiltrados.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            p.showToast(getActivity(), "Test-text2");
            if (recyclerView.canScrollVertically(-1) && !recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)){
                p.showToast(getActivity(),"f");
            }
        }
    });
```

Alguna idea de por qué esto no funciona en uno pero en otro sí? Como se soluciona este tema?

**Extra:**

Pareciera como que el listener del "NestedScroll" no funciona y por otra parte, el listener del "Recycler" si, aunque la validación de cuando este llegó al bottom tampoco pareciera estar funcionando. Estoy bastante perdido.

**Muchas gracias por leer!**

Answer (score 0):

para el adaptador de RecyclerView puedes utilizar el método **findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()**

Devuelve la posición del adaptador de la última vista completamente visible

para más información:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager

Edito:

Si necesitas desencadenar un evento cuando obtenga la última posición puedes utilizar addSOnScrollListener:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager.class.cast(recyclerView.getLayoutManager());
    int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
    int lastVisible = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

    boolean endHasBeenReached = lastVisible + 5 >= totalItemCount;
    if (totalItemCount > 0 && endHasBeenReached) {
        //you have reached to the bottom of your recycler view
    }
}
```

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40726438/android-detect-when-the-last-item-in-a-recyclerview-is-visible

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, considera revisar [answer], puedes también agregar un ejemplo de lo que comentas, saludos.

Comment: Gracias por responder @w4nm4 pero... que hago con esa última posición?

Comment: actualizo la respuesta. @TomasM

Comment: @w4nm4 gracias. Probé el código y sigue sin funcionar. Apenas deslizo un poquito y el if ya devuelve true

Comment: @w4nm4 De hecho, debugueando, el booleano siempre es true porque 14 > 10 siempre (totalItemCount siempre me devuelve 10 y lastVisible siempre me devuelve 9)

Answer (score 0):

Quien debe estar atento de que se este mostrando el ultimo item del recyclerView es el mismo recyclerView y se hace de la siguiente manera:

**Kotlin**

```
private fun initRecyclers() {
    val layoutManagerRecycler = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    layoutManagerRecycler.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL

    binding.recycler.layoutManager = layoutManagerRecycler
    binding.recycler.setHasFixedSize(true)

    binding.recyclerPicks.adapter = adapter ///SETEA TU ADAPTADOR

    binding.recyclerPicks.scrollLogicPag(layoutManagerRecyclerTournaments){ load ->
        if (load){
          ///ACCION CUANDO SE MUESTRA EL ULTIMO ITEM  
        }
     }
}
```

**Función de Extensión Para el Recycler**
Se encarga de escuchar el scroll del recycler

```
fun RecyclerView.scrollLogicPag(linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager, eventLoadMoreItems: EventReturnBoolean){
this.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        if (dy > 0) {
            eventLoadMoreItems.selection(loadMoreItemsList(linearLayoutManager))
        }
    }

    override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
        if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING || newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING) {
            eventLoadMoreItems.selection(loadMoreItemsList(linearLayoutManager))
        }
    }
})}
```

Esta **Función** encargada de validar si se esta mostrando el **ultimo item de la lista del recyclerView**.

```
   private fun loadMoreItemsList(linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager):Boolean {
        val currentItemOnScreen = linearLayoutManager.childCount
        val totalItem = linearLayoutManager.itemCount
        val scrollOutITem = linearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
        
        return (currentItemOnScreen + scrollOutITem == totalItem)
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero por que en kotlin? Trabajo con java :(

Comment: No hay problema, ambos lenguajes son muy similares, si entiendes las lineas las puedes migrar a Java.

Kotlin es el lenguaje oficial de android al igual que java, pero en kotlin el tiempo de desarrollo es mas rápido, te simplifica mucho el trabajo.

Comment: Sería una buena respuesta si la pregunta estuviera en el mismo lenguaje que la respuesta. Te sugiero que en lugar de comentarle al OP que trate de adaptar la respuesta de un lenguaje a otro, lo hagas tu mismo. Con ello probablemente recibirás votos a favor y completarás una respuesta correcta. Un saludo

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, espero que te sea útil para encontrar la solución a tu problema y si otra persona que programe en Kotlin tenga la misma duda le sea de ayuda el código!